# Read a hexadecimal value starting with \x from a text file

Tags: c++, boost-propertytree

I am sending data to a serial device using the function write() in boost::asio

In the code, I have hardcoded a string, which is detected by the serial device in hexadecimal format.

```
string test = "\x0C";
write(port, buffer(test.c_str(), test.size()));
```

However, If I read that value "\x0C" from a config file, which is in ASCII, it detects it as an ASCII value.

To read the string from the config file I am using the function boost::property_tree::xml_parser::read_xml.

```
read_xml(filename, pt);
command = pt.get<string>("conf.serial.command");
```

How could this value be treated in the same way as the other one?

Comment: If you want to send `\x0C` you have to escape the backslash like `"\\x0C"`, do you mean that?

Comment: No, when the string is read from a file, it would get \\, so it is not escaping anything...

Comment: How do you read from text file? You can maybe read it as binary with read() function.

Comment: The easiest would be to specify it as xml entity: `&#0C;`. Does it really have to be in the `\x0C`-format?

Comment: It can be in any format. So should I set the value &# instead? Why &#?

Comment: Since you parse your config file as xml, this is the xml-way to specify a character by its hex value

Comment: I will try tomorrow and will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches

### Xml Character References

Like a commenter offered, use [XML character references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview), as XML facilitates:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<conf>
    <serial>
        <command>&#0c;</command>
    </serial>
</conf>
```

When tested:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/640913a2022c6283)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

int main() {
    ptree pt;
    {
        std::istringstream iss("<conf><serial><command>&#0c;</command></serial></conf>");
        read_xml(iss, pt);
    }

    std::string const command = pt.get<std::string>("conf.serial.command");

    std::cout << "Correct? " << std::boolalpha << (command == "\x0c") << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Correct? true
```

### Use A Translator

You have a point, you **can** roll your own character escapes, if you provide the code to de-escape:

```
struct Escaped {
    using internal_type = std::string;
    using external_type = std::string;

    std::string get_value(std::string const& input) const {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        std::string result;
        parse(input.begin(), input.end(), *(
                    "\\x" >> uint_parser<uint8_t, 16, 2, 2>{}
                    | char_) , result);
        return result;
    }
};
```

You can then use that as a PopertyTree translator:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2148572b16c54f8d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Escaped {
    using internal_type = std::string;
    using external_type = std::string;

    std::string get_value(std::string const& input) const {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        std::string result;
        parse(input.begin(), input.end(), *(
                    "\\x" >> uint_parser<uint8_t, 16, 2, 2>{}
                    | char_) , result);
        return result;
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    {
        std::istringstream iss(R"(<conf><serial><command>\x0c</command></serial></conf>)");
        read_xml(iss, pt);
    }

    auto command = pt.get<std::string>("conf.serial.command", Escaped{});

    std::cout << "Correct? " << std::boolalpha << (command == "\x0c") << "\n";
}
```

### BONUS

Adding `put_value` to the translator: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbe3e6a67e22f646)</kbd>**

```
std::string put_value(std::string const& input) const {
    std::ostringstream result;
    for (uint8_t ch : input) {
        if (isprint(ch))
            result << ch;
        else
            result << "\\x" << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(ch);
    }
    return result.str();
}
```

So

```
pt.put("conf.serial.command", "\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\t\x77\x6frld\n", Escaped{});
std::cout << "New value (raw): " << pt.get<std::string>("conf.serial.command") << "\n";
```

Prints

```
New value (raw): hello\x09world\x0a
```

Comment: As a bonus made the translator writable (implementing `put_value`) **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbe3e6a67e22f646)**

Comment: And what happens if I have in the XML file a line like: echo -en "&#0C;&#0F" > /dev/device . It doesn't seem to work unless I hardcode it.

Comment: Oh the joy of escaping. You don't say what you're trying to achieve, but it looks like you want the XML to store a UNIX shell command. Assuming you want the UNIX shell command to be like `echo -en '\x0c\x0f' > /dev/device` you'd write this in the XML: [`echo -en &apos;\x0c\x0f&apos; &gt; /dev/device`](https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer) e.g. [doing that with property tree](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76242dae85b5c52f) - Key point: _just don't expect XML to be "simple" and "human serviceable". It is, but all text encodings crumble when pushed to the limits (e.g. with binary parts).

Comment: Yes, this is another config file. It is still considering the string as ascii. I am using std::system(cmd.c_str()); to execute the command.

Comment: Notice how in `echo -en &apos;\x0c\x0f&apos; &gt; /dev/device` we don't bother with your original question anymore (there's only one objective: XML encode the command, and the command doesn't contain unprintable characters anymore!). This is key. By now I'd suggest /just/ using base64 or hex encoding for the commands: [for example, hex encoding](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/365bab850ff402c3). This removes all of the confusion (people who think they can "just write a shell command in the XML file" - you can't)

Comment: Please take your time to actually see the repercussions of this. Text encoding and escaping is an issue (like character encoding and binary encoding) that permeates software and can only be done right in a pretty limited number of ways.